# xPath and max function

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xslt, xpath

I have xml file, and I would like to find node with oldest date.

Is it possible to do it without XLST?

Code:

```
var xml = @"<books>
                      <book>
                        <id>1</id>
                        <date>2011-01-02</date>
                      </book>
                      <book>
                        <id>2</id>
                        <date>2011-02-02</date>
                      </book>
                      <book>
                        <id>3</id>
                        <date>2011-03-01</date>
                      </book>
                    </books>
                    ";

XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);    
var result = document.XPathSelectElements("//books/book[max(????)]").ToList();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML, e.g.:

```
var result = document.Element("books")
            .Elements("book")
            .OrderByDescending(b => (DateTime)b.Element("date"))
            .First();
```

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be a direct way to do this. 
Some simple algorithm would be.. :

1. create date variable pretty with first node's date/
2. start iterating through xml
3. Read the time .. convert it using `translate`
4. check if its older than variable.
5. if yes  update your variable
6. Continue reading the xml in ether case until you reach end

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var result = document
                .Elements("books")
                .Elements("book")
                .Elements("date")
                .Min(e => DateTime.Parse(e.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var booksList = document.Descendants("book")
            .Min(b => Convert.ToDateTime(b.Element("date").Value));
```